# Get HTML content from htttps site in Python

Tags: python, ssl, https

I want to get the HTML code from a site and write it into a file. It works fine with a http site but if there is a SSL link then I get a lot of errors. Any idea how to deal with it?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import os
import re
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen

    with io.open('words.txt', 'a',encoding="utf-8") as g:
        url = "https://www.something.some"
        html = urlopen(url).read()
        print(html, file = g)
```

Here the errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Desktop\mined.py", line 54, in <module>
    html = urlopen(url).read()
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "....\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: *...then I get a lot of errors.* - It would actually help if you include the errors in your question. And even better would be to search using the error strings because it is not  unlikely that others had the same problem and solved it already.

Comment: I update it with the errors. And yes I tried befor to search them but in most case they dont do what I want, they just check the web page status, but i want the HTML content

Comment: When you say... _it works fine with a http site_... Are you trying to scrape the same site? (meaning, the only difference would be that `"http://www.something.some"` works and `"https://www.something.some"` doesn't) or are they different sites (different URLs)? Because a `403` HTTP status code means that you don't have permission to see something, which usually means you're not providing the username/password correctly, but this should happen in both the `http` and the `https` calls.

Comment: Actually it is not the same Site I just assumed it because other http are working and none of the https I tried worked

Comment: I found the answer i shoul have used headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

Comment: Please do not amend your question into an answer. Instead, add an answer below, and show what you changed to make it work. This is more helpful to future readers, who can still see what the problem was to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
import urllib

resp = urllib.urlopen('https://somewebsite.com') # open url
page = resp.read()                               # copy website source to 'page' variable
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")              # open txt file
text_file.write(page)                            # insert website source into txt file
text_file.close()                                # close file
```

Answer (score 0):

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Error `403 Forbidden` means that you got a successful SSL connection to the site but that the webserver explicitly refuses to serve you the content.
Probably the server does not want you to access the site with https and chances are high that you get the same error when using a browser to access the same URL. It might also be that the server is not properly configured for https yet.

If you can access exactly the same URL with the browser but not with your script their might be a filtering done by the server based on User-Agent or other things (i.e. to protect against access by non-browsers). In this case it would be useful to know the real URL of the site to help you better.